# How to set the microsecond to zero if not set by the user using Python datetime?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am trying to take in a user input, and create a time object from that string. Something like this:

```
import datetime
user_input = '14:24:41.992181'
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
```

However, lets say if the `user_input` was `'14:24:41'`, then I get a format error, which is understandable. What I want to do is for such an input, the microsecond precision for the time object would be set automatically to `000000`. I noticed something similar is done for timezones using `%z`, and its built into the `strptime()` method.

What is the ideal way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use try/except and handle the case when user input does not match the format string

```
import datetime
user_inputs = ['14:24:41.992181','14:24:41']
for user_input in user_inputs:
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, '%H:%M:%S')
    print(dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

output

```
14:24:41.992181
14:24:41.000000
```

Comment: You might want to note that the case which is expected to happen more often should be put in the `try` block. The `try..except` is usually faster than an `if` check if the call succeeds, but slower if the `except` block is actually entered (which is fine since exceptions should be exceptional events and therefore happen rarely).

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a simple check on the length of the input string, assuming you are expecting standardized inputs.

```
user_input = '14:24:41'
if len(user_input) == 8:
    user_input += '.000000'
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
```